# How to get jndi environment variables with junit test in Spring?

Tags: spring, jndi, spring-test

i have a problem with JNDI for test my application, not is the datasource, but load a configuration to environment. My application context the test:

```
<bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" id="appDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="jndiClient" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/client"/>
    <property name="jndiEnvironment">
        <props>
            <prop key="properties1">44</prop>
            <prop key="properties2">0</prop>
            <prop key="properties3">XPTO</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I need load this jndiClient. In my class:

```
    @Component
    public class FactoryLocator  {
         @Qualifier("jndiClient")
         @Autowired
         private JndiObjectFactoryBean jndiClient;
```

happened and the following error when I run the test:

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean br.com.simova.bob.factory.FactoryLocator.jndiClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiClient' defined in class path resource [test-appContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiClient' defined in class path resource [test-appContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:873)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:815)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:730)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 55 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:645)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:288)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getURLOrDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:325)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:95)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1545)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    ... 65 more
```

Thank for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First and foremost, your tests typically should *not* rely on JNDI being present in a test environment.

The whole point of using `JndiObjectFactoryBean` is so that you can decouple your application from a direct dependency on JNDI, using dependency injection of components instead.

With that in mind, I would highly recommend that you *never* inject an instance of `JndiObjectFactoryBean` into one of your application components. Instead, you should really be injecting the object *returned by the* `JndiObjectFactoryBean` into your components. By doing so, you can then configure a mock or stub of your component when writing unit and integration tests, thereby avoiding the need for JNDI for testing.

Now, if for some *very good* reason you simply must rely directly on JNDI, Spring does provide a mechanism for setting up an in-memory JNDI context. See the Javadoc for [SimpleNamingContextBuilder](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/jndi/SimpleNamingContextBuilder.html) for details.

Comment: Hi Sam, thank you for helping. I'm understand that you say, but this project requires use of a variable environment. 

I create SimpleNamingContextBuilder in my test with annotation @BeforeClass and worked. But i go try create a mock for my variables environment.

How do I not inject an instance of JndiObjectFactoryBean and returne a JndiObjectFactoryBean in application?

Comment: You don't use the `JndiObjectFactoryBean` within your application code at all. Instead, just inject the type of object that is retrieved by your `JndiObjectFactoryBean` from JDNI. I don't know your application, but it appears that it might be of type `JndiClient`. So use `@Autowired private JndiClient jndiClient` in that case.